# What is the Datatype of table generated at runtime

Tags: sql, db2

Below is how my query looks like

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 t1 WHERE col3='abc')
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.col1=t2.col1
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.col1=t3.col1
```

Datatype of all columns in table1, table2, table3 is varchar.

I am assuming when query is executed, firstly table1 will be stored in memory and then joining operations will be done on condition.

When table1 is stored in memory, is datatype of columns is still same as it was in table definition ? As it may throw some error if datatype is changed bcoz of the joining condition.

My this query is actually a view and iam getting following errors.
1. while running RUNSTATS on it:

> The utility could not generate statistics.  Error "-420" was
>   returned.. SQLCODE=-2310, SQLSTATE=     , DRIVER=3.61.75

2. While running this Query without using its view name( i mean running query directly)
   [jcc][t4][1026][11213][3.61.75] Bug check exception thrown due to an internal JCC error.  Please contact support.

> Message text: Error happened on server. Severity code 8. No exception
>   code returned from server. ERRORCODE=-4228, SQLSTATE=null

3. While running query `SELECT * from view`;

> Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function
>   "DECFLOAT".. SQLCODE=-420, SQLSTATE=22018, DRIVER=3.61.75

I am using db2 LUW 9.5

Comment: Try this: (SELECT * FROM table1 t1 WHERE col3='abc') t1

Comment: This may be a silly question but have you checked function DECFLOAT for an invalid character in a character string argument?

Comment: You can't assume "... firstly table1 will be stored in memory ...". The SQL optimizer decides the actual execution order.

Comment: @ChristianBarron I have not used any DECFLOAT function anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Actual Query was not having SELECT * . It was containing CASE based expression.
So, in THEN part the datatype was not same as the ELSE part.
Example: CASE WHEN 'a' THEN 'hello' ELSE 0

So because of this i was getting error, i have changed else part to '0'